# What are the installation procedures for Boost Spirit 3.0.0?

Tags: linux, installation, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

For this system configuration:

```
lubuntu 15.04
Ubuntu clang version 3.6.0-2ubuntu1 (tags/RELEASE_360/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.0)
libboost-dev 1.55.0.2
#define SPIRIT_VERSION_NOVEMBER_13_2008_0834AM
```

What are the installation procedures for Boost [Spirit 3.0.0](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2015/05/16/spirit-3-0-0/) given the above installed using Synaptic Package Manager?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the latest version.

Either

1. get the tar ball from http://boost.org or
2. get the lastest `master` branch from modular-boost: https://github.com/boostorg/spirit

The headers for X3 are in `boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp` and the `home/x3` directory.

Of course, start with the examples under `libs/spirit/example/x3/`

Comment: Does not describe how to to an install.

Comment: What doesn't? I thought you wanted to use Spirit X3. (rereads question) If you absolutely require a .deb package, copy the resulting tree to /usr/local/include/boost under checkinstall.

Comment: You linked that in the question. Could you try to use a sentence to clarify your needs?

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/master/include/boost/spirit/version.hpp says the version is SPIRIT 2008.  It seems unlikely that is is Spirit 3.0.0 as  http://boost-spirit.com/home/2015/05/16/spirit-3-0-0/ states that it expects "a compiler with c++14 capabilities".

Comment: I never referred to that header. Look in `x3/*`. The blog post clearly says the versions live side-by-side. So, this is what you're looking at (the other version, side by side)

Comment: There it is: **[`#define SPIRIT_X3_VERSION 0x3000`](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/master/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/version.hpp#L17)**

Comment: I am looking for a sequences of commands that will install Boost Spirit 3.0.0 on a linux system which already has a C++14 compiler and a version Boost installed.

Comment: That's the ["Getting Started Guide"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html). Don't forget Spirit (all versions) is a header only library. There's nothing to install outside of extracting/copying the header files somewhere.

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII *Boost.Spirit X3* is **header-only** library. Due to this reason you just need to checkout (clone) latest version of `master`/`develop` branch of @sehe's mentioned repository somwere, then add to your `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` path of right subdirectory of this copy of repository, which is containing headers (i.e. `boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp`).

Comment: @orient or get the publicly downloading release as everyone does :)

Comment: A later version of `develop` has more features and less bugs ;)